# mysql update on select row number

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I have next code:

```
SET @rownum=0;
UPDATE product_images AS t, (SELECT @rownum:=@rownum+1 rownum, id, rel 
FROM product_images WHERE product_id='227') AS r
SET t.rel = r.rownum
WHERE t.id = r.id
```

This is working excellent in phpmyadmin

BUT ... next code (witch is actually the same) but placed in php code

```
mysql_query ("
SET @rownum=0; 
UPDATE product_images AS t, 
(SELECT @rownum:=@rownum+1 rownum, product_images.* 
FROM product_images WHERE product_id='$pid') AS r
SET t.rel = r.rownum WHERE t.id = r.id ") or die(mysql_error());
```

GIVES ME ERROR : `"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'UPDATE product_images AS t, (SELECT @rownum:=@rownum+1 rownum, product_images.* ' at line 1"`

PLEASE HELP. THANK YOU.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

These are 2 queries you try to execute at once. That does not work with the `mysql_query` PHP method.

You actually don't need the first statement. Try

```
UPDATE product_images AS t
JOIN
(
    SELECT @rownum:=@rownum+1 rownum, id, rel
    FROM product_images
    CROSS JOIN (select @rownum := 0) rn
    WHERE product_id='227'
) AS r ON t.id = r.id
SET t.rel = r.rownum
```

to init the `@rownum` variable on the fly.

[Simplified SQLFiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/aa3ef/44)

Comment: Thank you! Thank you! Thank you! This is the solution. 10+

Answer (score 1):

MySQL's PHP driver does not allow multiple queries in a single query() call as a security measure against some forms of SQL injection attacks. You'll have to split your multi-query into multiple individual query() calls.

Comment: in other words : mysql_query ('SET @rownum := 0'); mysql_query('UPDATE...');